# A way to style a blazor EditForm

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

i am wondering if its possible to somehow style a blazor Editform with css or something else, I'm trying to figure out how i can change the position of the EditForm and change the width, height etc, if its even possible.

I tried to assign a class/id to the editform but that is not possible.

```
<EditForm Model="@esuper">
<label for="Firstname">First Name</label>
<InputText id="firstname" @bind-Value="firstName"></InputText>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add style on several ways, I post here an example using class, style and via element id:

```
<EditForm Model="@exampleModel" 
    OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" 
    id="MyEditForm"
    style="color: blue"
    class="MyEditClass"
    >
        <label>Some Text</label>
        <br/>
        <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <br/>
</EditForm>

<style>
    #MyEditForm {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .MyEditClass {
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
    }
</style>
```

Enjoy the result:

[image: changing EditForm css]

For detailed information about how this internally works, read about [Attribute splatting and arbitrary parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters).

Comment: What about styling all EditForms without using an ID or a class?